# Python class and ssh connections does not work well

Tags: python, ssh

Given the following code:

```
  class sshConnection():
      def getConnection(self,IP,USN,PSW):
        try:
            client = paramiko.SSHClient()
            client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            client.connect(IP,username=USN, password=PSW)
            channel = client.invoke_shell()
            t = channel.makefile('wb')
            stdout = channel.makefile('rb')
            print t    //The important lines
            return t   //The important lines
        except:
            return -1

   myConnection=sshConnection().getConnection("xx.xx.xx.xx","su","123456")
   print myConnection
```

outcome:

```
<paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 1 (open) window=1000 ->     <paramiko.Transport at 0xfcc990L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>>

<paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 1 (closed) -> <paramiko.Transport at 0xfcc930L (unconnected)>>>
```

Which means: Inside the class method, the `t` connection is connected, but after returning this connection descriptor, the connection is lost.

Why is that and how can i make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return and store somewhere the `client` and `channel` variables. They should be kept alive as long as `t` lives, but apparently paramiko does not obey Python convention.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I didn't know.

Answer (score 1):

Your client is going out of scope when the method returns, and that will automatically close the channel file. Try storing the client as a member, and keep the sshConnection around until you're done with the client, something like this;

```
import paramiko

class sshConnection():
    def getConnection(self,IP,USN,PSW):
      try:
          self.client = paramiko.SSHClient()
          self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
          self.client.connect(IP,username=USN, password=PSW)
          channel = self.client.invoke_shell()
          self.stdin = channel.makefile('wb')
          self.stdout = channel.makefile('rb')
          print self.stdin    # The important lines
          return 0   # The important lines
      except:
          return -1

conn = sshConnection()
print conn.getConnection("ubuntu-vm","ic","out69ets")
print conn.stdin


$ python test.py 
<paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 1 (open) window=2097152 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0xb3abcd0L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>>
<paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 1 (open) window=2097152 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0xb3abcd0L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>>
```

Of course, to clean things up a bit, you may want to hide stdin/stdout and use them through other methods on sshConnection instead, that way you'll only have to keep track of that instead of multiple files *and* a connection.